# Large discrepancy in netlogs and Android data usage statistic

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, android, tethering

As my internet connection I use a mobile hotspot set up on a Xiamo Redmi note 8 running Android 9.0. The only device connected to the hotspot is my laptop running Ubuntu 19.1.

I've noticed that I am getting a high data consumption (~3GB/day), which seems excessive especially given the fact that I mostly only use the laptop for browsing the internet and streaming music from youtube (quality is set to 144p.)

Since the Android phone is reporting that 99% of the data usage is coming from the hotspot, I've set up netlogs to monitor bandwith usage. After a few hour's session I am quite surprised in the discrepancy I am seeing

[image]

[image]
How could it be that the phone is claiming 3x more of data usage? The phone was on airplane mode for a day until I've started the experiment today.

How can I determine what is causing this discrepancy and what is actually hogging all this data?

Edit. As one of the comments suggests, it looks like this was an issue with UDP not being tracked by nethogs. Usage statistic obtained by nethogs seems to confirm proper data usage.

Comment: The information on the Internet indicate that NetHogs only covers TCP data, not UDP data. Some streaming services use UDP, may be this explains the difference?

Comment: @Robert You are right that was the issue apparently. If you wish to post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Now I am not sure if my comment is relly true. Looking at the [source code of nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs/blob/a46b3d6f97337b12ac5818bc03135b7d1f246ec8/src/main.cpp) there is also UDP mentioned. May be the limitation to TCP was only true up to a certain version? I would check the help text of nethogs if UDP is mentioned.

Comment: @Robert My quick googling suggested that UDP might be the case. Given that ifconfig is accounting for all traffic I figured that might be it.